# Displaying decimal places

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I'm writing a report, in which I need to display decimal places only where necessary

For example

123.0000 should be displayed as 123
123.4670 should be displayed as 123.467
235.4345 should be displayed as 235.4345

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I'v figured it out. Just need an expression #,###.####

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is 2 option.

One way if you using sp , so good to convert in db side.

You can cast or convert as float simple

```
select cast (123.4670 as float), cast (123.000 as float)
```

or

if you are using tables, then use [Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187573/ssrs-expression-to-format-two-decimal-places-does-not-show-zeros) function to modify

```
=Format(Fields!CUL1.Value, "#,##0.##")
```

Comment: Tnx, I change my answer, my though is simple its good if you taken from db side.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept this answer although I did figure it out before :)

Comment: Revoked my downvote, because you now changed your answer. I'd still like to note that the exact same thing can be achieved when putting the format string as custom number format in the properties as I suggested.

Comment: Yes dear, your answer will static or fixed to use format. If we need dynamically allow decimal value at that time fix format will give always same result. so we use formula to allow decimal or not.

Comment: Did you even check my answer? In the dialog I'm referring to there's a "Custom format" input field into which you can enter the format string! This is **not** limited to fixed formats!! I'm not trying to get the accepted answer here, but my answer is also correct and should not be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select Cast(value as decimal(18,3))
```

or

```
select cast(columnName as decimal(18,3)) from  table_name
```

Here `3` is the decimal places number. shows like `18.009,2.000,4.333` etc.

If use `2` then it'll show like `18.00,2.00,4.33` etc.