# SSRS formatting and exporting to Excel

Tags: reporting-services

I need to display a value like 100.02 as 100.02 if it is 100.00 it should display as 100 so I use the expression

```
=Replace(Round(Fields!Test.Value,2),".00","")
```

This displays in the desired format but

> when I export to Excel it gets converted to Text .

Any suggestions on rectifying this issue are greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS expression to format two decimal places does not show zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187573/ssrs-expression-to-format-two-decimal-places-does-not-show-zeros)

Comment: By using the replace you are converting the number to text. Check the above SO link and format your number as shown in the answers and it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the Text Box's **FORMAT** property, use an expression that determines whether the number is an integer or not and use an expression based on that to set the format of the cell.

```
=IIF(Fields!Test.Value = INT(Fields!Test.Value), "N0", "N2")
```

Remember to remove the Replace and Round.