# SSRS Format Custom Number

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that I am running that will end up with values like this

```
100.00
99.98
98.80
100.00
```

I have a custom format set up where I want to remove the decimals after the 100s and keep all other decimal places.  Here is my expression

```
=IIF(Fields!Field1.Value Is "100.00", "100", Fields!Field1.Value)
```

This works for the 100 but it removes the 0 after 98.80.  Here is what I end up with.

```
100
99.98
98.8
100
```

Is there a way to not remove that single trailing 0?

Comment: Have you tried using the round function? - round to 2 decimal places

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187573/ssrs-expression-to-format-two-decimal-places-does-not-show-zeros

Comment: @John I tired that and could not get any of those examples to work.  However, I did not try it with the conditional statement

Comment: @Ryan let me try that as well

Comment: @im not sure it will work but was thinking if you just round all of your figures and then have the if statement for 100 it might ignore your 0 issue

Comment: Round for whatever reason still removes the trailing 0.  Format messes up all of the data.  for 100 I end up with 1100 when i do a format F2.  I am removing the trailing zeroes on 100 when I move the data into SSRS.  Should I remove those lines and try to do all formatting in SSRS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would leav ethe value expression alone, just let that be the field value.

I would do this in the format expression of the cell/textbox instead. So the format expression would be something like.

```
=IIF(Fields!Field1.Value = 100, "f0", "f2")
```

This assumes your data is numeric.

Comment: Thanks Alan.  That worked.  So what is the f0 doing?

Comment: '`f'` formats a number `without thousand separators` and the 0 formats with zero decimal places. f2 does the same to 2 decimal places. You can also use n0, n1, n2 etc... `'n'` formats `with thousand separators` so for example, `1234.1234` formatted with `n2` would give `1,234.12` (assuming comma is the locales thousand separator)

Answer (score 0):

=IIF(Fields!Field1.Value Is "100.00", "100", Format(Fields!Field1.Value,"##.##"))

Comment: That one seems to mess up the data.  This one keeps them in the same format but still leaves the trailing 0.  =IIF(Fields!Field1.Value Is "100.00", "100", FormatNumber(Fields!Field1.Value, "##.##")).  I must have done something else as this should work.